# curl url that has a space

Tags: javascript, json, url, curl

I am trying to curl a url

```
http://whatever/[a] bc.vmd
```

Since there is a space after [a], curl is reporting errors :/

I tried %20 like

```
http://whatever/[a]%20bc.vmd #curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 51
```

How do I get over this?

Thanks,

Vik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap the url in between the double qoutes(`"`) if you are using this from commandline. Also escape the `[ ]` characters using `\`.

```
curl "http://whatever/\[a\] bc.vmd"
```

If you are using from your code, then [encode](http://urlencoder.net) the uri portion of the url. For example the space will be `%20`

```
http://whatever/%5Ba%5D%20bc.vmd
```